# Finding expected perimeter and area of rectangle using random distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, gamma-function

Hi i have a question: A random rectangle is formed in the following way- Base X is generated from Gamma(1, λ) distribution and after generating the base, the height Y is chosen uniformly on the interval [0,X]. It asks to find the expected perimeter and expected area of the random rectangle.

My approach for perimeter: E(2(X+H))= E[E(2(X+H)|X)]

```
                                    = E[2E(X|X) +2E(H|X)

                                    = E[2X + 2 E(H)]

                                    = 1 + 2/λ

        for area:    E(XH) = E[E(XH|X)]

                           = E[XE(H|X)]

                           = ....
```

Could you let me know if my approach to perimeter is right and also give me ideas as to how to approach the next steps for the area?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you mean perimeter?

Comment: yes thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base is given by $X$, the height by $\Theta X$ where $X \sim \Gamma(1,\lambda)$ and $\Theta \sim \text{unif}(0,1)$.

Presumably $X$ and $\Theta$ are independent.

Then the perimeter is $P = 2X + 2 \Theta X$, and $EP = 2 E X + 2 E \Theta E X =
2\frac{1}{\lambda}+ 2 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\lambda} = \frac{3}{\lambda}$.

The area is $A = \Theta X^2$, and $E A = E \Theta E X^2 = E \Theta (\operatorname{Var}X+(E X)^2)  = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\lambda^2}+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}$

Comment: Choosing the height uniformly on $[0,X]$ is exactly the same as choosing $\Theta$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ and then multiplying by $X$. It is a matter of preference, for me it is clearer.

Comment: i just want to carlify one thing. A=ΘX^2, and EA=EΘEX^2 you mean EA=EΘX * EX^2 right? Also would you be able to explain why A=ΘX^2 instead of x * ΘX

Comment: Since $A=\Theta X^2$, and $\Theta, X$ are independent, we have $EA = (E \Theta) (E (X^2)))$. I'm not sure I understand the difference between $\Theta X^2$ and $X (\Theta X)$?

Comment: Thank you so much i was confusing myself with the notation but now i understand. Would you kindly have a look at my final question at your convenience? Thank you very much once again copper. [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511912/finding-varx2]

Answer (score 0):

Conditional on $X$, height is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $X$ so its expectation is $X/2$. So expected value of perimeter should be $E[2X+2E[Y|X]]=E[2X+2(X/2)]=3E[X]$. Similarly, expected value of area should be expected value of $E[X^2/2]=(Var[X]+E[X]^2)/2$.

Comment: Thanks user96614. Could you explain a little bit further on how you get 3E[X]? Step by step would really help me to understand a little bit better.